# Popover not showing the view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, uipopovercontroller

i am using a `UIPopoverController`.

In this popover i am loading a custom view which has a navigation bar and a table view.
When i present the popover it only shows the navigation bar and table view is not shown.
Please tell me how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try `self.myPopoverController.doWhatImThinkingAndNotWhatTheCodeSays = YES;` **OR** post some relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. Actually i was unable to give the permittedArrowDirections parameter because the direction was not fixed. So I passed a "NO" in the parameter and it works. Thanks everyone for their help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

just check that you Add `UITableView` as a SubView of your custom view or not..

also try with this code...

```
    UIViewController *viewTemp = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    viewTemp.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400);
    yourTable.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400);
    [viewTemp.view addSubview:yourTable];///Add Table as a SubView of your custom view

    UIPopoverController *popTemp = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:viewTemp];

    [popTemp presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(810.0, 35.0, 300, 210)  /// just set frame which from you want to show this popover view ... you can set like yourButton.frame;
                            inView:self.view
          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                          animated:YES];
    CGSize size = {300 , 400};// give your size which you want...

    popTemp=nil;
```